# How to disable immediate focus in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-design-library

I use TextInputLayout (+ search) in my NavigationDrawer. When user toggle this drawer, the cursor focus appears immediately on TextInputLayout field.

[image]

Is it possible not to get focus on this field until user will click on it?

Thanks !

Comment: add it in your xml android:focusable="false"

Comment: Solution is there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558493/how-to-remove-focus-from-textinputlayout-when-page-loads/45009744#45009744

Answer (score 61, accepted):

in your root view use this attribute:

```
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: but IS your root view supposed to be focusable? probably not :|

Answer (score 6):

None of the answers helped in my case. What I did was the following:

```
editText.post(() -> {
        textInputLayout.setHintAnimationEnabled(false);
        editText.clearFocus();
        textInputLayout.setHintAnimationEnabled(true);
    });
```

This is available starting from design support library v23.

Comment: Its worked on some devices but not all devices

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your onCreate():

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

or add this into your manifest in your activities entry:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Comment: Not working if you setText to that EditText inside of your textInputLayout

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem , just add another EditText and hide it

```
        <EditText
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="0dp" />
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/NghiPhep_TextInputLayout_GhiChu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextHintLabel"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            >
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/NghiPhep_txt_GhiChu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:hint="Ghi chú"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arial_rounded"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```